# Now() is not inserting datetime upon registration

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

As the title says..

Here is my code inside register.php

```
if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
    $register_data = array(
        'username'      => $_POST['username'],
        'password'      => $_POST['password'],
        'first_name'    => $_POST['first_name'],
        'last_name'     => $_POST['last_name'],
        'signup'        => 'now()',
        'email'         => $_POST['email'],
        'email_code'    => md5($_POST['username'] + microtime())
    );

    register_user($register_data);
    header('Location: register.php?success');
    exit();
```

And here is my the part of my users functions file that deals with registration.

```
function register_user($register_data) {
array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');
$register_data['password'] = md5($register_data['password']);

$fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`';
$data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\'';

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` ($fields) VALUES ($data)");
email($register_data['email'], 'Activate your account', "Hello " . $register_data['first_name'] . ",\n\nYou need to activate your account, so use the link below:\n\nhttp://www.site.com/activate.php?email=" . $register_data['email'] . "&email_code=" . $register_data['email_code'] . "\n\n - admin");
}
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect you might be getting `'now()'` instead of `now()` in your SQL (i.e. a string rather than a function call). More than suspect, given what your `implode` does.

Comment: what is data type of signup field?

Comment: use this function date("Y-m-d H:i:s")

Comment: Thank you all for your input, date("Y-m-d etc") worked for me, thank you gayan.

Comment: And just to be saying what everyone itches to say. mysql_* is deprecated and should no longer be used, the same could be said about MD5 for passwords.

Comment: thanks Jim, yeah was tempted to type "inb4 mysqli" in the question but decided against it, trust me it's on my todo list.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I looked through the code, as I said in comments: you are quoting your function call. `now()` is a function call that gives you a datetime; `'now()'` is no kind of datetime at all. You need to figure out a way to not bundle that particular field in with the rest when you do the delimited `implode`. Even better, use a better way to access the database: mysqli or PDO would both be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `implode` statement results in correct way, For example if you are inserting `username` and `signup` fields the query must be

```
INSERT INTO `users` (username, signup) VALUES ('abcd', now())
```

It should

```
 INSERT INTO `users` (username, signup) VALUES ('abcd', 'now()' )
```